# softlayer api get order reference from pending invoice list

Tags: python-3.x, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

SoftLayer API: How can I get order reference from pending invoice list

```
import SoftLayer
client  =  SoftLayer.Client(api_key ='XXXXXX', username = 'xxxxxx')
pending_invoice_list = client['Account'].getPendingInvoice(mask='mask.items')
```

i can get only invoice line item only ,how i can get order reference

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this code can help you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


#Get Next Invoice TOP level Items. 


import SoftLayer
from pprint import pprint as pp

# A valid Username
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=USERNAME,
                                          api_key=API_KEY)


accountService = client['SoftLayer_Account']

object_Mask="mask[createDate, description, hostName, domainName, lastBillDate, orderItem[id,order[id]]]"

try:

    result = accountService.getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems(mask = object_Mask)

    pp(result)

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    """"
    If there was an error returned from the SoftLayer API then bomb out with the
    error message.
    """""
    print("Unable to retrieve the Account?s latest pending Invoice " )
    print(e )
```

.

```
""""
Get pending Invoice. 

This script retrieve an account's latest open (pending) invoice.
 See below for more details.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Account
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getPendingInvoice
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice_Item

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. sldn@softlayer.com
"""""
import SoftLayer
from pprint import pprint as pp

# A valid Username
USERNAME = 'set-me'
# A valid ApiKey token, generate one for you or your users, or view yours at https://control.softlayer.com/account/users
API_KEY = 'set-me'

client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=USERNAME,
                                          api_key=API_KEY)


accountService = client['SoftLayer_Account']

object_Mask='mask[id, invoiceTopLevelItems[categoryCode, description, billingItemId, id, domainName, ' \
            'hostName, billingItem[id,orderItem[id,order[id]]]]]' #Retrieves only specified properties
                                                                  #in the object mask.

try:
    """"
    getPendingInvoice() method will an retrieve a SoftLayer_Billing_Item object.
    """"",
    result = accountService.getPendingInvoice(mask = object_Mask)

    pp(result)

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    """"
    If there was an error returned from the SoftLayer API then bomb out with the
    error message.
    """""
    print("Unable to retrieve the Account’s latest pending Invoice")
```

The code aboce will return the InvoiveTopLevel items for your pending invoice and their associated orders .

Comment: its doesn't return order id only returns billing id

Comment: the billingItem is the object that contains the orderId if you are not able to see it is because you do not have enough permissions I recomend you to use the master user to test it

Comment: i have try with master account its returns  order id empty string

Comment: your billing invoice contains bare metal servers or virtual guests? they should have an orderid

Comment: i am master brand account ,i have n number of customer ,they place order both virtual guests and bare metal server, while i send invoice from master account need to specify order id to the customer

Comment: how i can get order reference  ??. cloud you please help

Comment: the result that you are getting from pending invoice must not contain those items (the bare metals and VSI) that's why you are not seeing what you are expecting. Try using this method instead http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems  this method is going to return all the items that are going to be in your next invoice. I added the example in my post

Comment: the above example not return order id

Comment: i got output like this  [
 {'createDate': '2017-05-18T00:31:38-05:00',
  'description': '#1315597 - Star Test_002',
  'lastBillDate': ''},
 {'createDate': '2017-05-18T02:49:36-05:00',
  'description': '#1351173 - RHIMJHIM ISPAT',
  'lastBillDate': ''}
]

Comment: for me the two request return the orderID

Comment: you try with master brand account ?

Comment: for me the two request return the orderID, you should get somethong like this  {
        "createDate": "2016-02-12T11:07:59-06:00",
        "description": "Dual Intel Xeon E5-2690 v3 (12 Cores, 2.60 GHz)",
        "domainName": "open-test.ibmcloud.com",
        "hostName": "100-node-compute100",
        "lastBillDate": "2017-06-03T23:08:24-06:00",
        "orderItem": {
           id: 1111,
           order: {
              id: 22222
           }       
         }    
    },

Comment: you items must not have an orderItem

Comment: also the description for the item that you posted it seems not to belong to a server or VSI, the description should contain the information about the cores, but in your case I do not see that

Comment: how we can get above details( what you mention) from master brand account

Comment: wait, let me get this, do you have a brand account? and are you looking to get that information from your customer accounts?

Comment: Yes i need all customer pending invoice from brand account

Comment: You only can get that information using the master account of each child account of your brand account and call the method, you can use impersonation for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718672/impersonating-another-user-in-softlayer