# How to access the API using a BAP/Agent account?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

For instance, if you want to use the "SoftLayer_Brand" API, and make a call to "SoftLayer_Brand::getAllOwnedAccounts", I would assume that you could do that as long as you have a BAP/Agent account?

But I can't find any place that lists the API key needed to make the API calls, like the one you find once logged into one of the accounts in the normal Customer Portal.

Basically what I'm trying to achive, is to be able to list (for example) all hardware our customers have in their SoftLayer accounts, or pull out invoices across all accounts, but just can't find where the API key is listed for my BAP/Agent account.

Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and make a call to "SoftLayer_Brand::getAllOwnedAccounts", I would
>   assume that you could do that as long as you have a BAP/Agent account?

Yep that is rigth you need to have a BAP/Agent account

> But I can't find any place that lists the API key needed to make the
>   API calls

to list the API keys you need to impersonate to that account and call the http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_user_customer/getapiauthenticationkeys. the impersonation only can be done using SOAP request see this for an example [Impersonating another user in SoftLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718672/impersonating-another-user-in-softlayer)

Once you have the API key for the user you can list all the hardware mashcines or invoices for the account

Comment: That's interesting, but I'm still a bit at loss as to how to make the initial API request? For instance, in the impersonation example you linked, you still need to provide an "<authToken>$TOKEN</authToken>", but I have no idea where that is listed in the Agent Portal?
It's that initial call, somehow using my BAP/Agent credentials, that I'm struggelig with. Once I have that, I can iterate over the accounts, and do what I need to do, as you describe.

Comment: Ah! Never mind! I figured that part out now. :)
For some reason, it never hit me to log into the normal Customer Portal (control.softlayer.com) using by BAP/Agent credentials, I've just used it with the agent.softlayer.com portal. Once I logged into the Customer Portal, I could generate my API keys from there, and can now access all the account information through the brand.
Thanks for your help!